# Uploading fails for some files, Client refreshes multiple times (CFS)

Tags: javascript, file, meteor, upload, filesystems

I'm uploading multiple files on submission of a form.

This is the image upload input (html):

```
    <form class="form-inline" id="cost-estimate-form">
        <div class="form-field-short col s12 m6">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">insert_photo</i>
            <label for="input-file">Upload photos</label>
            <input id="input-file" type="file" name="images" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, application/pdf" multiple/> <!-- todo: ugly on safari -->
        </div>
<!-- rest-->
        <button class="btn waves-effect col s6 m3 offset-m6" type="submit" name="action">Submit
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
```

And the .js

```
'submit #cost-estimate-form': function(event, tmpl){
    event.preventDefault();

    let files;
    if(event.target.images) {
        files = event.target.images.files;
    }
    Meteor.call('travelRequests.insert', tmpl.data, function(err, trId) {
        if (err) {
            alertError(err.message);
        }
        else {
            if (files) {
                var imageDetails = [];
                for (var i = 0, j = 0, ln = files.length; i < ln; i++) {
                    Image.insert(files[i], function (err, fileObj) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Error uploading image: ');
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log('[DB] insert image(id=' + fileObj._id);
                            j++;
                            let imagePath = '/uploads/images-' + fileObj._id + '-' + fileObj.name();
                            imageDetails.push({id: fileObj._id, name: fileObj.name(), path: imagePath});
                            if (j === ln) {  // when last file is successful
                                Meteor.call('travel.addImages', trId, imageDetails,
                                    function (err, _) {
                                        if (err) alertError(err.reason);
                                    });
                                console.log('travel.addImages');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });

    Router.go('travel_requests_list');
```

`Meteor.call('travelRequests.insert'...` creates an entity. Then I try to update the images uploaded for that entity after uploading the files with `Meteor.call('travel.addImages',...`.

However, when clicking submit button on the form, the next screen refreshes multiple times and I get error in client:

```
cfs_power-queue.js:525 Error: "Queue" network [undefined], Error
at cfs_upload-http.js:382
at cfs_upload-http.js:108
at underscore.js:794
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (cfs_upload-http.js:167)
```

And in the mongodb, some files are completely uploaded and some are not:

Example complete file:

```
{
    "_id" : "MEWTZaXLX9gvx5utc",
    "original" : {
        "name" : "IMG_3867.JPG",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-07-19T02:57:55Z"),
        "size" : 4231984,
        "type" : "image/jpeg"
    },
    "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-15T02:30:40.204Z"),
    "copies" : {
        "images" : {
            "name" : "IMG_3867.JPG",
            "type" : "image/jpeg",
            "size" : 4231984,
            "key" : "images-MEWTZaXLX9gvx5utc-IMG_3867.JPG",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-15T02:30:40Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-09-15T02:30:40Z")
        }
    }
}
```

Example incomplete file:

```
{
    "_id" : "cgHcSCRPvzgekW6Ai",
    "original" : {
        "name" : "IMG_3869.JPG",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-07-19T02:58:10Z"),
        "size" : 4108047,
        "type" : "image/jpeg"
    },
    "chunkSize" : 2097152,
    "chunkCount" : 1,
    "chunkSum" : 2
}
```

Collection definition:

```
Image = new FS.Collection("images", {
    /* the file director: .meteor/local/uploads */
    stores:[new FS.Store.FileSystem("images",{path:Meteor.settings.uploadRoot+"/uploads"})],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*', 'application/pdf'] //allow only images and pdf in this FS.Collection
        }
    }
});

if(Meteor.isServer){
    Image.allow({
        'insert': function () {
            return true;
        },
        'update': function () {
            return true;
        },
        'download':function(){
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Why does this happen? Should I wait for file upload to finish before routing to the next screen? How do I do that if that is the problem?

I'm new to meteor so any help is appreciated.

Comment: post your collection definition here.

Comment: @AnkurSoni : Done. Please check.

Comment: Which version of Meteor you using btw? it seems very old I guess.

Comment: @AnkurSoni: version is `Meteor 1.4.3.2`

Answer (score 0):

As you are not using kadira's FlowRouter, I may be not be the right person to answer about the redirection issues as Router mechanism can hold data inside routes as well which is very bad. As per latest Meteor conventions, Subscription must be at template level implementation.

But, I can tell you that you can wait for completion of image upload. When the image is uploaded successfully only then you can perform next operation which can be either redirection to next page or any other operation.

Below is the code to wait for the completion of your image upload. The basic Idea is the `url` of image is generated only when the Image gets uploaded completely. so we wait for `url` to be generated, Once we receive `url`, it means we are done.

```
var myImage = event.target.images.files[0];
if(myImage){
    var myFile = new FS.File(myImage);
    Images.insert(myFile, function(err, result){
      if(!err){
        var liveQuery = Images.find(result._id).observe({
        changed: function(newImage, oldImage) {
          if (newImage.url() != null) {
            liveQuery.stop();
            // Here the image is uploaded successfully.
          }
        }
        });
      } else {
        //console.log(err);
      }
    });
}
```